# Packer Autoinstall French Language & Keyboard Layout

Tags: packer

I’m trying to make a Proxmox template using Packer and I've been struggling to make it choose the French Language.

Here's a portion of my `user-data` file :

```
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  locale: fr_FR
  keyboard:
    layout: fr
```

It's stuck in here:
[image]

I went through packer docs and couldn't find any piece of documentation about that user-data file :/ Anyone knows where I can get this information please ?

Comment: Where did you get this idea for user-data from? its not a packer feature. user-data is normally used as part of bootstrapping the system. this would be OS dependent and not something for packer. https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#user-data

Comment: @ChrisDoyle tbh, I got that packer script for a Youtuber's Github

Comment: Normally when I do packer builds like ubuntu with a user-data file I mount the user-data file as a cd_file like `cd_files = ["./myfiles/user-data"]` then ubuntu references these files as part of its boot process. But the key here is packer doesnt know or care what this user-data file is or contains. its specific to the OS and you need to reference the OS docs on how you should present it to the OS. Then use packer to mount or present it like that.

Comment: Alright thanks alot ! Can you put this as an answer so I can validate it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packer its self doesnt know or care what a user-data file is. That is something thats OS specific for example like in ubuntu https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#user-data. Where as other OS like windows or RHEL might have a different method to setup a system. Using the ubuntu example the way I have done this previously is with a setup like below.

In my case I am using vsphere but the idea should work on other sources like AWS EBS etc. I also have a setup.sh script I run as part of the build to configure a few other things after the system is bootstrapped

```
/ubuntu20.04
  /config-files
    user-data
    meta-data
  /setup
    setup.sh
  template.pkr.hcl
  var.pkr.hcl
```

**user-data**

```yaml
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
    version: 1
    early-commands:
        # Stop ssh for packer
        - sudo systemctl stop ssh
    locale: en_GB
    keyboard:
        layout: en
        variant: gb
# plus other stuff in my setup
```

**setup.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo '> Cleaning all audit logs ...'
if [ -f /var/log/audit/audit.log ]; then
cat /dev/null > /var/log/audit/audit.log
fi
if [ -f /var/log/wtmp ]; then
cat /dev/null > /var/log/wtmp
fi
if [ -f /var/log/lastlog ]; then
cat /dev/null > /var/log/lastlog
fi

echo '> Cleaning apt-get ...'
apt-get clean
# Cleans the machine-id.
echo '> Cleaning the machine-id ...'
truncate -s 0 /etc/machine-id
rm /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
ln -s /etc/machine-id /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
```

**template.pkr.hcl**

```
source "vsphere-iso" "ubuntu" {

  cd_files = [
    "./config-files/user-data",
    "./config-files/meta-data"
  ]
  cd_label = "cidata"
  boot_order   = "disk,cdrom,floppy"
  boot_wait    = "3s"
  boot_command = [
    "<esc><esc><esc>",
    "<enter><wait>",
    "/casper/vmlinuz ",
    "root=/dev/sr0 ",
    "initrd=/casper/initrd ",
    "autoinstall ",
    "ds=nocloud-net;",
    "<enter>"
  ]
  shutdown_command = "echo '${var.ssh_password}' | sudo -S -E shutdown -P now"
  shutdown_timeout = "15m"

  #
  #some other stuff 
  #
}

build {
  sources = ["source.vsphere-iso.ubuntu"]

  provisioner "shell" {
    execute_command  = "echo '${var.ssh_password}' | {{.Vars}} sudo -S -E bash '{{.Path}}'"
    environment_vars = [
      "BUILD_USERNAME=${var.ssh_username}",
    ]
    scripts           = ["./setup/setup.sh"]
    expect_disconnect = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Using this method, it seems like packer is mounting the user-data file. But for whatever reason, it's still being stuck on that "Choose Language" Screen :/

Comment: which OS and version are you using? which source type? do you have anything else in your user-data file that might be invalid and causing cloud-init to fail parsing it. you should be able to connect to the target machine being built and look in the OS logs under /var/log

Comment: can you add this to your source `boot_order   = "disk,cdrom,floppy"` I will update the answer but you need to tell the target system it can boot from cdrom

Comment: I have updated the answer with some additional fields such as the boot command. Please note that this bootcommand will be OS and version dependant, the boot command here is for ubuntu 20.04 but when i built ubuntu 22.04 this command didnt work and I had to change the boot command to something else for 22.04

Comment: sorry made one more edit as the boot command I pasted was the 22.04 one instead of 20.04.

Comment: I got it working, the proxmox plugin works with an HTTP Server, So I needed to setup the network bridge so my Proxmox could communicate with the HTTP Server. Thanks alot!

Comment: Nice, glad you got it sorted, took me a day or so to work all this out originally. Now i keep it in my github to reference for future.